# Dynamic image for Jumbotron on WordPress Custom Theme

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

What is the correct process to make your jumbotron image dynamic (user changeable) via the WordPress customizer. 
Currently on my customers custom theme www.windupgram.co.uk I am using a static image, which I have to change when required.

I would like to give the client an option to change the image whenever they want.

Many thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add support for the built-in Custom Header feature:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/

Or use the Customize API to add your own control to the Customizer for selecting the image:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

The Custom Header feature is basically just a shortcut for using the Customize API to add a control, but you have less control over what the field is named etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced custom field plugin, then call the field back to your static image. If you are new to ACF plugin, read their docs here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

Most importantly look at the Location box. The location box allows you to create a set of rules which decide when and where to add these fields to the edit screen / post object. See more here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/

For example, the image field is

```
<?php the_field('yourimage'); ?>
```

Your code should be like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <img src="<?php the_field('yourimage'); ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

Then you don't need the static jumbotron image.

Comment: Thanks Noobie, I will give this a go. I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Customize API worked for me. I created at new folder called inc and in there created a new file called customize.php

In that file I added this code:

```
    <?php
 function gramophone_customize_register($wp_customize){

    // Showcase Section
    $wp_customize->add_section('showcase', array(
        'title'          => __('Showcase', 'gramophone'),
        'description'    => sprintf( __('Options for showcase area', 'gramophone')
        ),
        'priority'       => 130,
    ));

    // Image Setting
      $wp_customize->add_setting('showcase_image', array(
        'default' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . 'img/Gramophonebannernew2.jpg',
        'type'    => 'theme_mod'

     ));

     // Image Control
     $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'showcase_image', array(
         'label'    => __('Background Image', 'gramophone'),
         'section'  => 'showcase',
         'settings' => 'showcase_image',
         'priority' => 1,
     )));

}

   add_action('customize_register','gramophone_customize_register');
```

Then in my functions.php I added this code

```
   require get_template_directory(). '/inc/customizer.php';
```

My in header.php I added the styles for the jumbotron

```
  <style>
    .jumbotron{

          margin: 0;

      }
    .showcase{
              background:url(<?php echo get_theme_mod('showcase_image', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/Gramophonebannernew2.jpg'); ?>) no-repeat center center;
              background-size: cover;
              height: 100vh;
          }

  </style>
```

And finally added a showcase class to my jumbotron

```
       <div class="jumbotron showcase">

   </div>
```

Now when I go into the customizer I can change the image to what every I want. If not image is chosen then default one I placed in my customizer.php will be used.